# Align div in the same offset top than another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My question is pretty simple. I have `div1` that has a variable `offset().top` depending on other elements of the page. I want to insert an `absolute` div next to it (basically with the same absolute `top`) either with just css or with javascript too.

[image]

HTML looks something like

```
<div>
   <div id="div2">stuff</div>
</div>
<div>
   <div>some divs</div>
   <div id="div1">div1 stuff </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why can't you assign the offset in the same way as you do for `div1`. Some code would be useful.

Comment: Add relative wrapper for your div1.

Comment: @Turnip Div1 already exists in the page, and I am inserting div2 later in the page. And when I do something like `$('.fr_down').css('top', $('#extra-final').offset().top)` it goes much lower than it should

Comment: Does you `div2` have an initial `top` when it's first inserted in the `DOM`?

Comment: @callback, yes. I insert it without specifying the top offset, and it's always inserted in the same place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since in the comments you say you want to place `div2` after it has been inserted in the DOM, you can try the following:

```
$('#div2').css('top', $('#div1').offset().top - $('#div2').offset().top)
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
#div1, #div2 { display:inline-block; }
```

and

```
<div id="div3">
  <div>
    <div id="div2">stuff</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>some divs</div>
    <div id="div1">div1 stuff </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: even with adding a parent div to div1 & div2 ?

Comment: Yes, I tried both having div2 first and then div1 and vice versa, but it didnt place them correctly